# Getting global var to use in a function

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I'm working with this code to play and pause several audios:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var getaudio;
  var audiostatus = 'off';
  var current_id;
  jQuery(document).on('click touchend', '.speaker', function() {
    elemento = jQuery(this);
    current_id = elemento.children("audio").attr("id");
    clase = current_id.replace(/player/, '');

    if (!jQuery('.c'+clase).hasClass("speakerplay")) {
       getaudio = jQuery('#'+current_id)[0];
       if (audiostatus == 'off') {
         jQuery('.c'+clase).addClass('speakerplay');
         getaudio.load();
         getaudio.play();
         audiostatus = 'on';
         return false;
     } else if (audiostatus == 'on') {
       jQuery('.c'+clase).addClass('speakerplay');
       getaudio.play()
     }
   } else if (jQuery('.speaker').hasClass("speakerplay")) {
     getaudio.pause();
     jQuery('.c'+clase).removeClass('speakerplay');
     audiostatus = 'on';
   }
  });

  // Here is my problem: I need to get the value of current_id...
  jQuery('#'+current_id).on('ended', function() {
    jQuery('.speaker').removeClass('speakerplay');
    audiostatus = 'off';
  });
});
```

In the last function I want to remove the class 'speakerplay' once the audio reached the end, but I can't get the value of current_id

Could anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add the handler to the document as well so you have access to the correct element thorugh `$(this)` as you do in the click handler? current_id does not even have to be global or a variable for that matter, since it's only used to select the correct element.

Comment: Thanks Shilly for your reply!
But I'm affraid I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you show me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

don't use 
var current_id;

use window.current_id directly

```
window.current_id = elemento.children("audio").attr("id");

jQuery('#'+window.current_id).on('ended', function() {
```

Comment: Thanks Geo Paul for replying!
I've tried as you told but it doesn't works yet...
If I write 'window.current_id in console, I get the right value, but the function seems not to works...
Any thoughts?

Comment: Replace '#'+window.current_id with just window.current_id